# Forward and reverse proxy on the same port

Tags: proxy, squid

I'd like to configure Squid 3.5 (or anything else that could do the job) to act as both a reverse proxy and a forward proxy on the same port.

Leaving a port in the default forward proxy mode makes Squid return an error, when receiving a `GET /` request, as it expects to see a protocol and hostname. Configuring it in the `accel` reverse proxy mode makes it not support the `CONNECT` method.

I see that older versions of Squid had a `httpd_accel_with_proxy` config option, but it's deprecated now. I've also tried adding the protocol and hostname to requests that begin with `/` using the `url_rewrite_program` config option, but Squid appears to check url validity before rewriting them.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Typically a forward proxy is used to cache or restrict internet traffic, outgoing requests. A reverse proxy is usually used to cache incoming requests, or load balance across many servers. They're different functions, often on different servers, and are quite different functions. Why do you need them on the same server / port?

Comment: @Tim I want to make a forward proxy on the https port to hide my origin from websites and my destination from local network eavesdroppers. But I'd also like for it to appear as web host, not a proxy, to said eavesdroppers and bots scanning well known ports.

Comment: I'm not sure your approach is viable. I suggest a better approach would be to ask another question that more clearly outlines your desired end result, including why you want to do this, and ask the community for suggestions.

Comment: That's not how you do it. You don't make a "reverse proxy", you implement access control.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Care to elaborate? I have access control lists. The domain I want my proxy to appear to be hosting is in the first acl, which is allowed `http_access`. To reach anything else, you need to be in the `authenticated_users` acl. Doesn't make a port in the forward proxy mode to understand `GET /` as `GET http://not-a-proxy.example.com/`

Comment: You should not be trying to make a reverse proxy
 appear to be hosting anything at all!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I guess I could have phrased it better. My goal is to make my forward proxy appear to be hosting a website. To that end, I wanted it to also act as a reverse proxy on the same port I would be using for forward proxying.

Comment: I understood, the point is that you should not be trying to do that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton and could you please explain what makes you say that?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, Apache's [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) and its submodule mod_proxy_connect suit my needs perfectly. You can turn any virtual host into a forward proxy with SSL and authentication.

Even if you don't want your proxy to appear as a web server, if you just want a forward proxy, I'd say it's easier to set up than Squid, considering that doesn't support SSL out of the box.